# Getting "NoMethodError: undefined method `upload' for nil:NilClass" error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cloudinary, rails-activestorage

I am developing an android application that uses Ruby on Rails in the back end. I used Rails for creating the `REST API`. I need to upload images along with other data. Basically, I have `"user"` and `"Event"` objects. Each user can create many events. The user can attach an image along with the description of the event. I use Postgres DB for the textual data store, and it works fine. But the problem is when I use cloud api `"Cloudinary"` for the `images`. I could't know what the problem is. I am getting the following error:

```
  {
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "exception": "#<NoMethodError: undefined method `upload' for nil:NilClass>",
    "traces": {
        "Application Trace": [
            {
                "exception_object_id": 78590280,
                "id": 26,
                "trace": "app/controllers/events_controller.rb:23:in `create'"
            }
        ],
        "Framework Trace": [
            {
                "exception_object_id": 78590280,
                "id": 0,
                "trace": "activestorage (6.0.1) app/models/active_storage/blob.rb:194:in `upload_without_unfurling'"
            },
            {
                "exception_object_id": 78590280,
                "id": 1,
                "trace": "activestorage (6.0.1) lib/active_storage/attached/changes/create_one.rb:25:in `upload'"
            },.....
```

When I test the API from Postman, I have done the following steps:

I added the following gems in `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'cloudinary', require: false


gem 'activestorage-cloudinary-service'
```

Then I run:

```
bundle
rails active_storage:install
rails db:migrate
```

I added the following in `config/storage.yml`:

```
    cloudinary:
  service: Cloudinary
  cloud_name: <%= ENV['CLOUDINARY_CLOUD_NAME'] %>
  api_key:    <%= ENV['CLOUDINARY_API_KEY'] %>
  api_secret: <%= ENV['CLOUDINARY_API_SECRET'] %>
```

And I added the following line in the `config/environments/**` files:

```
config.active_storage.service = :cloudinary
```

Routes.rb loks like the following:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :events do
    get :event_image, on: :member
  end
  resources :users
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end
```

And `EventsController` is the following:

```
class EventsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_event, only: [:show, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /events
  def index
    @events = Event.all.with_attached_event_image

    render json: @events.map {|event|
    event.as_json.merge({event_image: url_for(event.event_image)})}
  end


  # GET /events/1
  def show
  event = Event.find(params[:id])
  render json: event.attributes.merge(event_image: url_for(event.event_image))

  end
  # POST /events
  def create
    @event = Event.new(event_params)
  #  Cloudinary::Uploader.upload(@event.event_image)
    if @event.save
      render json: @event, status: :created, location: @event
    else
      render json: @event.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /events/1
  def update
    if @event.update(event_params)
      render json: @event
    else
      render json: @event.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  # DELETE /events/1
  def destroy
     @event.destroy
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_event
      @event = Event.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Only allow a trusted parameter "white list" through.
    def event_params
      params.require(:event).permit(:title, :description, :country, :city, :event_location, :event_date, :event_time, :event_status, :user_id, :event_image)
    end
end
```

Remember: The API works well using local storage! The error is when I switch the storage service to `:cloudinary`. Can anyone help, please?

Comment: what's event.rb look like?

Comment: @JoshBrody  

event.rb is as follow:  
    
    `class Event < ApplicationRecord  
    belongs_to :user  
    has_one_attached :event_image  
    end`

Comment: Cloudinary has recently released their official ActiveStorage support in the cloudinary_gem - https://cloudinary.com/documentation/rails_activestorage. I would suggest using that specifically rather than any 3rd party gems for this.

Comment: @Aleksandar Kostadinov  I have tried it, though couldnt work for me. I switched to Carrierwave. It works fine with Carrierwave.  Thanks for your help